# Summarise with rowwise produces empty values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and want to summarise rowwise by taking the mean on columns that start with a specific name. Therefore, this should summarise the columns and only return individual columns for each naming parameter.

For example:

```
iris %>% aggregate(. ~ Species, data=., sum) %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(summarise(across(starts_with(c('Sepal','Petal')), mean), .groups = "rowwise"))
```

produces:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width               
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <rowwise_df[,0]>
1 setosa             250.        171.         73.1        12.3                 
2 versicolor         297.        138.        213          66.3                 
3 virginica          329.        149.        278.        101.
```

However, I was expecting a dataframe like the following:

```
 Species    Sepal   Petal                   
1 setosa     210.5  41.5 
..
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is mixing tidyverse with base R.  We may do this directly in `tidyverse` i.e. after grouping by 'Species', get the column wise sum with `across`, then get the `rowMeans` of the numeric columns

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  transmute(Species, Sepal = rowMeans(across(starts_with("Sepal"))),
      Petal = rowMeans(across(starts_with("Petal"))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Species    Sepal Petal
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa      211.  42.7
2 versicolor  218. 140. 
3 virginica   239. 189.
```

---

If we want to use `rowwise` in `groups` (note that `rowwise` would be slower compared to vectorized `rowMeans`)

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum), .groups = 'rowwise') %>% 
  transmute(Sepal = mean(c_across(starts_with("Sepal"))), 
    Petal = mean(c_across(starts_with("Petal")))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Species    Sepal Petal
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa      211.  42.7
2 versicolor  218. 140. 
3 virginica   239. 189.
```

Comment: However this is taking the average on all columns where its numeric. Instead I wanted to only take the average depending on those columns starting with `Sepal` or `Petal`. Did you see the expected output above?

Comment: @dollarbill here, all the columns other than Species have Sepal, or Petal as prefix.

Comment: Yes they do, I think my intension was not signalled effectively. It is my fault, essentially, for prefix `Sepal` we apply mean and create one column, and for prefix `Petal` we take mean and create one column. So only two columns remain. It probably cannot be done in a single mutate that may be why its confusing

Comment: @dollarbill sorry your usage was confusing.  For different blocks of columns, it needs to do separately or have to split up into long format and then do group by mean

Comment: That is what I was thinking; I really like your approach, as it turns out `apply` may be more effective if wanting to apply different functions i.e. ```transmute(Sepal = rowMeans(across(starts_with("Sepal"))),Petal = apply(across(starts_with("Petal")), 1, function(x)weighted.mean(x, w=c(0.7, 0.3))))```

Comment: @dollarbill you can use `pmap` for that i.e. `transmute(Petal = pmap_dbl(across(starts_with("Petal")), ~ weighted.mean(c(...), w = c(0.7, 0.3))))`

Comment: Very good point! given that pmap applies on each row. Good catch!